# Trying to create collisions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

```
var i:int = 0;
stage.focus=stage;
var Walls:Array = [Wall,Wall1];

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,HitDetection);
function HitDetection(event:Event):void{
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);
function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{ 
    {
       if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
     if (KeemStar1.hitTestObject(Walls[i])) {
trace("1")
    KeemStar1.x -=-0.1;
        }
        else
        {
            KeemStar1.x -=0.1;
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
      {
         if (KeemStar1.hitTestObject(Walls[i])) {
             KeemStar1.x -=-0.1;
trace ("n")
        }
        else
        {
            KeemStar1.x +=0.1;
        }
      }
   }
}
}
}
```

It only collides with the first Wall, instead of every wall in the array. I've tried everything but I can't figure it out  I'm kind of new to actionscrip3 so I'm not sure what to do.  Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't looping through the array as you need to. It should look more like this:

```
for (var i: int = 0; i < Walls.length; i++){
    // code for collision detection against Walls[i]
}
```

that code will loop through as many items as you have in that array, checking collision against each one.

Also your `if` statements are bracketed totally wrong. Should be:

```
if (condition){
    // code
}
```

replace `condition` with whatever you want (like `KeemStar1.hitTestObject(Walls[i])`) and replace `//code` with what should happen if the condition is true.

You should learn to indent the right amount and get rid of all that crazy white space. It makes it almost impossible to read. I had to go through and correct your indents and white space excess just to realize you had your brackets wrong.